# Linking NavigationController to the AppDelegate using storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

I am a newbie and I am playing with storyboard.. I started with a simple empty application, added a new storyboard. Created a `UINavigationController` which has a viewController. My question is how do I link an iVar from the `AppDelegate` to the `UINavigationController`. Any pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Two choices:

1- Access the AppDelegate (Not a good practice)

```
YourAppDelegate* appDelegate= (YourAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
yourObj = appDelegate.obj;
```

2- Have a reference to `YourMainViewController` (which is the top view controller of `UINavigationController`) in the `AppDelegate` and set its properties there.